Activating Demonic hordes’s ability in response to it’s upkeep cost
Can I activate Demonic Hordes’s ability in the upkeep in response to having to play BBB?

Yes, you can do this. When your upkeep begins, the ability will trigger and go on the stack. At that point you will get priority and can activate activated abilities. When that triggered ability resolves, you will still have to pay the mana or else you'll sacrifice a land of an opponent's choice. The "tap Demonic Hordes" part of the penalty just won't hurt you because it's already tapped.


Upkeep Step


503.1. The upkeep step has no turn-based actions. Once it begins, the active player gets priority. (See rule 117, “Timing and Priority.”)

503.1a Any abilities that triggered during the untap step and any abilities that triggered at the beginning of the upkeep are put onto the stack before the active player gets priority; the order in which they triggered doesn’t matter. (See rule 603, “Handling Triggered Abilities.”)



